# Not able to add style to Notebook frames in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am using this style to customize Tkinter Notebook which working fine for `TNotebook.Tab` but it is not applying any style to `TNotebook.Frame` can you please let me know how I change the Notebook Frame background colors?

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create('appstyle', parent = 'alt',
    settings = {
   "TNotebook": {
        "configure": {
            "tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]
        }
    },
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {
            "padding": [10, 1],
            "background": "#eee"
        },
        "map": {
            "background": [("selected", "LightGoldenRod")],
            "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]
        }
    },
   "TNotebook.Frame": {
        "configure": {
            "background": "red"
        }
    }
    }
)
style.theme_use('appstyle')
```

Comment: For the 'alt' theme,  `style.layout('TNotebook.Frame')` returns the error `TclError: Layout TNotebook.Frame not found`, so that's certainly why your configuration of `TNotebook.Frame` is applied to nothing. Where do you want this red background?

Comment: Hi , I want to change the Notebook Frames background color

Comment: By frames, you mean the widgets you add inside the tabs (with `notebook.add(widget, **kwargs)`) ? If so, I think their background is set by the style for the widget class (in your case TFrame), not by the style of the notebook.